# Логирование и сохранение в php monolog

Tags: php

Всем привет, мне нужно сделать лог вставки в базу данных и сохранить этот лог в файл.Наведите пожалуйста пример или документацию ибо я не нашел.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста. Например, пользователь заполняет форму на сайте и вам нужно что-бы все что ввел пользователь и отправил сохранялось в БД?

Comment: Да и с помощью библиотеки monolog сохранить в файл

Comment: 1. Приписывайте к формам запросы к БД в виде INSERTов. 2. Почитайте док-ию к данной библиотеке если такая имеется, вроде как на гитхабе у них есть README.